# Placing "markers" in MathJax math expressions

Tags: mathjax

Suppose I have some equation, say:

$$\underbrace{ \frac{a}{b} }_{c}$$

And, I want to get the location of the $c$ in the HTML/CSS/SVG output of MathJax.

Is there a way to do this? I.e. I'd like to do something like:

$$\underbrace{ \frac{a}{b} }_{c\invisiblemarkerXYZ}$$

then be able to do a query to get the DOM element corresponding with invisiblemarkerXYZ

Thanks!

EDIT this is what I want to do:

Equation 1 = $$\underbrace{\frac{a}{b}}{A}$$

Equation 2 = $$A = \sum_{i=1}^n i$$

Now, I want to draw a line (via SVG) of the two A's. Thus, I need some way to obtain the location of the MathJax elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\cssId{XYZ}{c}` to set the `id="XYZ"` on the element used for the `c`, and can then use `document.getElementById("XYZ")` to obtain that DOM element.  But the output from MathJax's HTML-CSS and SVG processors is not designed to be manipulated after the fact.  For example, in general you will not be able to get the dimensions of the element from the HTML-CSS output as the `offsetHeight` and `offsetWidth` may not be what you expect them to be.  (The height is frequently set to 0, for example.)

Can you say something more about what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Interesting. Added a blurb about what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Wow, you're one of the developers of MathJax. This is amazing. Can you please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539639/mathjax-intermediate-format-svg-output ? I'm trying to build a WYGIWYG technical editor? (Think XFig cross WYSIWYG MathJax, all in SVG). Thanks!